# How to use question mark and colon in an url with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to open that url with codeigniter:

http://example.com/controller/function/land-for-sale-6350-m2-40k-euro-is-that-too-much-?-ad-code:608/54990

here is the error i've got:

Disallowed Key Characters: -ad-code:608/54990

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-üöçşığzA-ÜÖÇŞİĞZ\', :/?0-9~%._+&*!-';

what to do fix that problem ?

Comment: Question marks in PHP detail when a global GET variable is declared, regardless of mod_rewrite or not. You may want to rethink the way you are setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in your config file (application > config > config.php)

```
Line 129 - $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

You can add any characters that you need in there.... but proceed with caution